# How to use JQuery animate() as toggle?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I hava a button and I added click event. When I click this button I added some animation using jquery animate() and when I click 2nd time I want to get back in previous position.

here is my code:

```
$("button").click(function () {
            $("h1").animate({
                opacity: "0.5",
                width: "50px",
                height: " 100px"
            }, 1000);
        });
```

Comment: Do the animation with CSS and then just toggle the class

Comment: good idea. any process using jquery? like toggleAnimate or something?

Comment: As I've said. Do the [animation with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/) (`h1.make-me-fanzy { ... }`) and then `.toggleClass("make-me-fanzy")`

Comment: i got you. thanks it is working. but how add 1000ms transition? I tried transition property, this is not working.